# Cinnamon for Bisamim

Tags: havdalah, smell

Can you use cinnamon for Bisamim at havdalah? Which is better: ground cinnamon or whole sticks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see online ([here](http://www.sachet.com/store/WsDefault.asp?One=265) and [here](http://www.jewfaq.org/prayer/havdalah.htm)): Yes. Don't know about the second half, probably depends which way gives a stronger smell...